# Pythagoras theorem and ratios of sides

Tags: geometry

In a right angle LAB angle L is right angle and AM is perpendicular to AB. Prove that LA^2 : LB^2 = AM : MB. 
This can be proved using similar triangle principles. But I am interested to prove this using only Pythagoras the

Comment: Polish your question a bit. Please be a little more helpful by producing the diagram of the triangle in question.

Comment: The problem as stated is incorrect. Presumably you meant that M lies on AB and that LM is perpendicular to AB.

Answer (score 0):

Let $LA = a ,LB = b ; AM = x ,BM = y$

From Pythagoras' theorem on ALB, 
$$
a^2 + b^2 = (x+y)^2 \tag{1}
$$

From Pythagoras' theorem on AML and LMB ,
$$
a^2-b^2 = x^2-y^2 \tag{2}
$$
Adding equations (1) & (2) , we get 
$$
a^2=x(x+y)
$$
Subtracting equation (2) from (1) we have 
$$
b^2=y(x+y)
$$ 
From which we get 
$$
\frac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{x}{y}
$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Dear Sir, Please give the complete solution

Comment: @user86508. It's not this site's policy to provide complete solutions to simple problems. We expect you to do some of the work yourself. deepu's solution is fine; if there's a step you don't understand, ask for clarification in a comment.